# Executing a command (only) when prior jobs are finished in Bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, jobs

I am trying to ensure that a command is run serially after parallel commands have been terminated.

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3
```

In the above example, `command1` and `command2` are launched in background at the same time, but `command3` is run soon after.  I know this is expected behaviour in Bash, but I was wondering if there was a way for `command3` to be launched after `command1` and `command2` are terminated.

It is probably possible to do:

```
(command1; touch done1) &
(command2; touch done2) &
while [ ! -f done1 ] && [ ! -f done2 ]; do sleep 1000; done
command3
```

...but if a more elegant solution is available I will take it. The join needs to be passive as these commands are destined to be used in PBS queues. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wait` without arguments to wait for all previous jobs to complete:

```
command1 &
command2 &
wait
command3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  This'll do the trick.  Just to push it a but further, had I wanted something like `((command1 &; command2 &; wait; command3) &; (commandA &; commandB &; wait; commandC) &)` to behave such that the first `wait` is dependent on `command1` and `command2` and the second `wait`, on `commandA` and `commandB` only, I would need to specify job IDs to `wait`?

Comment: That works pretty much the way you want. `wait` only waits for commands in the current shell. `( .. )` creates a subshell, so `a & ( b & ( c & ); wait )` will only wait for `b`. Also, `&;` is invalid; just use `&`.

Comment: Might be useful to mention the `jobs` command will give a list of running jobs - `jobs -p` gives just the pids.